# Vue seems to be calling all custom directives more often than expected. Why, can this be avoided?

Tags: vue.js

I'm only a few months into vue coming from an angularjs background.

I built my first custom directive and it's acting a little odd to me.

```
Vue.directive('silly',{
  componentUpdated: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    console.log("it was called");
  }
});
```

and I place it on my form like this:

```
<form id="opt-cpmt-form" method="post" class="mri-grid mri-p-none">
    <label for="one">name<input  id="one" type="text"  v-model="local.name" v-silly class="form-control"></label><br/>
    <label for="two">phone<input v-isnumeric id="two" type="text" v-model="local.phone" class="form-control "></label><br/>
    <label for="two">zip<input id="three" type="text" v-model="local.zip"  class="form-control" ></label><br/>
  </form>
```

It kinda works...the part that I didn't understand is that my v-silly directive is called when any of the other fields are updated too.  It seems to be related to the model but I only want my directive called when the field changes.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

It's an expected behaviour as the component updates whenever a piece of its data object is updated. To not trigger the logic too many times, you can create an event listener when the directive is bound to its parent and then run the logic when a desired event happens.

```js
Vue.directive('silly', {
  bind(el) {
    this.updateCallback = function(event) {
      // Your logic
    };
    el.addEventListener('input', this.updateCallback);
  },
  unbind(el) {
    el.removeEventListener('input', this.updateCallback);
  }
});
```

In case you plan to listen to the changes of `v-model` directive, bear in mind that it uses different events based on what element it's bound to. You can read more about that topic in [v-model documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage).

> v-model internally uses different properties and emits different events for different input elements:
>
> - `text` and `textarea` elements use **`value`** property and **`input`** event;
> - `checkbox` and `radiobutton` inputs use **`checked`** property and **`change`** event;
> - `select` fields use **`value`** as a prop and `change` as an event.

Also, from my experience when it comes to the form validation; I've done it using the directives and regretted it afterwards. I found it best to create reusable functions and create the custom form validation for every form. See [custom form validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html#Using-Custom-Validation) for more.

Comment: wow impressed by your response, not only an answer but also an observation of what I was trying to do and an alternative path.  You are absolutely correct that I am trying to do form validation. I'm choosing the directive approach because we need to support older browsers that don't always do validation highlighting properly.  If I have to do the highlighting myself, I'm thinking that I'll validate the form by looking for the classes that my directives are leaving on each input. Seems doable but I'd welcome a better approach to scratch both itches (highlighting and form validation). Thanks!

Comment: also, the code snippet you provided errors with Error in directive silly bind hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'updateCallback' of undefined"

Comment: @samantha be careful not to use arrow functions. You probably lost scope when declaring the callback. Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yftg20h3/

Comment: If it does not work, you can always create a variable before declaring the directive https://jsfiddle.net/d6rcwax7/